# jquery nested li click event calls multiple times

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following structure.

```
<ul id="browser" class="filetree">

        <li><span class="folder">Folder 1</span>

            <ul>

                <li><span class="file">Item 1.1</span></li>

            </ul>

        </li>

        <li><span class="folder">Folder 2</span>

            <ul>

                <li><span class="folder">Subfolder 2.1</span>

                    <ul id="folder21">

                        <li><span class="file">File 2.1.1</span></li>

                        <li><span class="file">File 2.1.2</span></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>

                <li><span class="file">File 2.2</span></li>

            </ul>

        </li>

        <li class="closed"><span class="folder">Folder 3 (closed at start)</span>

            <ul>

                <li><span class="file">File 3.1</span></li>

            </ul>

        </li>

        <li><span class="file">File 4</span></li>

    </ul>
```

In js
I have the following function.

```
$("#browser li").click(function(){


});
```

When I clicked on li File 2.1.1. 
The function calls 3 times

first time for li File 2.1.1 , second time for li Subfolder 2.1 and third time for li Folder 2.

Can anyone give me the solution to call the function exactly once?

Your Help is greatly Appriciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is because you have **many** `li` elements under `#broswer`.

Try this instead:

```
$("#browser>li").click(function(){
    //only direct children of #browser
    //your code
});
```

Or you can use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$("#browser li").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    //your code
});
```

Comment: your correct in that #browser>li is direct child of #browser but that would mean any #browser>li>li wouldnt be called?

Comment: @AbstractChaos exactly, but all those other `li`'s are inside a direct child of `#browser`

Comment: but then if for example the OP does click on file.2.1.1 which is $browser>li>li>li then it wouldnt fire?, you will catch it at the bubble up tho i guess. depends on requirements to usefulness of that

Comment: @AbstractChaos yep, it all will be caught by the top `li` element :-)

Comment: But presumably, in real life, the OP will want to be able to inspect the clicked element and figure out which File the user meant; that won't work properly without specific click events on the lowest level elements, I think.  Using stopPropagation seems like a better solution to me.

Comment: @JacobM hence I have that as the 2nd option.

Comment: stopPrapogation worked great after checking if $(this) has parents who are li! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Change your function to

```
$("#browser li").click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
   //do your other stuff

});
```

That way, the click on the lower-level `li` won't "bubble up" to the higher level `li`.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact events "bubble" up your dom so you if you click

File 2.1.1, it will also be heard by File 2.1 and File 2 to fix this change event to

```
$("#browser li").click(function(e){
  //Your code here
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the click event on the li object add another element (in example span) and handle click in that. This way can still bubble for higher events just doesn't bubble through nested li.

```js
//Run the following to see the no li bubble result 

$(".nobubble").on('click',function(){
    $("#result").append($(this).attr("data-id") +"<br />")
   });

//uncomment the following to see the li bubble result
/*$(".bubble").on('click',function(){
    $("#result").append($(this).attr("data-id") +"<br />")
   });*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="bubble" data-id="li-a"><span  class="nobubble" data-id="span-a">a</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="bubble" data-id="li-b"><span class="nobubble" data-id="span-b">b</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="result">
</div>
```