# how to stop nested event calling in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here, i am beginner in jquery and i am building a web page in which i am facing an issue.
in this, when i click the article1 or article2 then section and page click event are automatically called. i want to stop calling them.

here is page.html

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="section">
        <div id="article1">this is article 1</div>
        <div id="article2">this is article 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is page.js

```
$('#page').on('click', function () {
    alert('page');
});
$('#section').on('click', function () {
    alert('section');
});
$('#article1').on('click', function () {
    alert('article1');
});
$('#article2').on('click', function () {
    alert('article1');
});
```

here is page.css

```
#page {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color:brown;
}
#section {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:red;
}
#article1 {
    background-color:green;
}
#article2 {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

please suggest any solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery nested li click event calls multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123829/jquery-nested-li-click-event-calls-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`evt.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation):

```
$('#page').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    alert('page');
});
$('#section').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    alert('section');
});
$('#article1').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    alert('article1');
});
$('#article2').on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    alert('article1');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeozffjr/5/)

Answer (score -1):

using

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

here is a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsn8n0yp/

Answer (score -1):

use stopPropagation() man.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#page').on('click', function (e) {       
        e.stopPropagation();
    alert('page');  
    });
    $('#section').on('click', function (e) {       
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('section');
    });
    $('#article1').on('click', function (e) {    
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('article1');
    });
    $('#article2').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('article1');
    });

})
```